# Criar Array TEdit em tempo de Execução;

Tags: delphi

Com o seguinte código, crio uma quantidade X de edits:

```
var
  x : integer;
  var2: integer;
begin
  var2 := strtoint(edit2.Text);
  for x := 1 to var2 do
  begin
    ArrayEdit[x] := TEdit.Create(Self);
    ArrayEdit[x].Parent:= Self;
    ArrayEdit[x].Left := 83 + x * 50;
    ArrayEdit[x].Top := 130;
    ArrayEdit[x].Width := 41;
    ArrayEdit[x].Height :=24;
    ArrayEdit[x].Name := 'edit'+ inttostr(x+20);
    ArrayEdit[x].Text := '';
    ArrayEdit[x].ShowHint:=true;
    ArrayEdit[x].Hint:='edit'+ inttostr(x+20);
  end;
end;
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Preciso pegar os valores de cada edit criado, e receber em uma variável para ser usada depois. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Receber em uma variável? Não seria melhor criar um vetor para armazenar já que são vários Edits. A menos que você realize algum tipo de operação em tempo de execução inclusive e que utilize apenas uma variável.

Comment: Sim, acabei pensando melhor a minha ideia foi a seguinte: adicionar os edit em um outro vetor, e dai atribuir para uma variável.
Pois tenho que usar esses valores que serão escritos no edit criado em tempo de execução em um Tmemo.

Comment: E já implementou? Funcionou?

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado.

Comment: Se você quiser pode colocar a resposta aqui na sua própria pergunta para que todos saibam o que você fez, sua pergunta teve 3 votos positivos até o momento pode ser que ajude alguém (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi adicionado os valores para algumas variáveis, de acordo com o índice necessário.
Bem simples, mas para o meu caso era isso.

```
   res := ArrayEdit[1].text;
   res2 := ArrayEdit[2].Text;
   res3 := ArrayEdit[3].text;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu `ArrayEdit` é um array de Objetos do tipo `TEdit` então basta você acessa-lo na posição que terá um TEdit, ai é só acessar a propriedade `Text` do mesmo.

```
 for x := 1 to length(ArrayEdit) do
  begin
    ArrayEdit[x].text
  end;
```